# В чем различие между типами int, unsigned int и size_t?

Tags: типы-данных

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем различие между int, unsigned int и size_t. Вот unsigned int не содержит знака, точнее если даже бит четности равен 1, то число все равно положительно в отличие от signed int. А зачем тогда нужны size_t, wchar_t и прочее?